# VPN with Network Connections GUI - unable to access Internet

Tags: openvpn, networkmanager, linuxmint

I am trying to setup VPN connection using Network Connections GUI. To do so I pick an option to import vpn configuration and manually enter VPN credentials. So far so good, I can get connected. The issue is that when I connect to the VPN using GUI I cannot open any public website like google.com or similar (but intranet sites are working fine).

When I use the same configuration file and credentials to connect with terminal OpenVPN (version 2.5.5) with command `sudo openvpn --config ./vpn-conf/client.ovpn --auth-user-pass ./vpn-conf/ovpn.creds` it works fine.

What option do I miss in the GUI so that it highjacks all the connection instead of using VPN for intranet only?

Comment: Forced tunneling.

Comment: Huh? I cannot find such option...

Comment: Every VPN product ever created has the setting. Sometimes it is called "Use default gateway in remote network". Does it exist in that GUI? Maybe someone else can speak to that. You can confirm it by inspecting the routing table.